# Catching ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, exception, divide-by-zero

In my exception handling, I'm trying to catch ZeroDivisionError's but for some reason, the code is still doing the division by 0 and not bringing back an error. I must be doing something wrong but I can't seem to place it.

I have tried to move the division elsewhere in the function, and move the division error catch as well.

```
filename = "numbers.txt"

def main():
    total = 0.0
    number = 0.0
    counter = 0
    average = 0


    #Open the numbers.txt file
    try:
        infile = open(filename, 'r')

        #Read the values from the file
        for line in infile:
            counter = counter + 1
            number = float(line)
            total += number

        average = total / counter

        #Close the file
        infile.close()

    except IOError:
        print('An error occurred trying to read the file', end=' ')
        print(filename, '.', sep='')

    except ValueError:
        print('Non-numeric data found in the file', end=' ')
        print(filename, '.', sep='')

    except Exception as err:
        print('A general exception occurred.')
        print(err)

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Cannot devide by zero.')

    else:
        print('Average:', average)
        print('Processing Complete. No errors detected.')




# Call the main function.
main()
```

I'm expecting the result to return the error message when dividing by zero, but it's returning zero as the answer instead.

Comment: can you share the output you get? actually you did `except Exception as err`. That's why

Comment: At the very least, `except ZeroDivisionError` should be above `except Exception as err`, since `ZeroDivisionError` is derived from `Exception`.  In other words, in its current state, the `ZeroDivisionError` block will never be hit because division by zero will be handled in the `Exception` block instead.

Comment: @0x5453 I just switched the except ZeroDivisionError to the last except and still no luck.

Comment: I've just been putting a series of numbers that I'm using to test the exception errors. I've tried all zeros, a couple of zeros. Every time it pulls back 0.0 as the average instead of giving me a ZeroDivisionError

Comment: I'd recommend reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  This should be pretty easy to figure out with a debugger or simply by throwing in some `print` statements.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the order that you catch exceptions.  Since all exceptions in Python inherit from the Exception base class, you are never getting the ZeroDivision exception since it is caught by handling of Exception.  Try this:

```
except IOError:
    print('An error occurred trying to read the file', end=' ')
    print(filename, '.', sep='')

except ValueError:
    print('Non-numeric data found in the file', end=' ')
    print(filename, '.', sep='')

except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Cannot devide by zero.')

except Exception as err:
    print('A general exception occurred.')
    print(err)

else:
    print('Average:', average)
    print('Processing Complete. No errors detected.')
```

Comment: I switched it to this, but still no luck. It's still giving me 0.0 as my output instead of pulling up the error.

Comment: Is there another exception being caught by the handling of Exception.?

Comment: There is not. It's coming back as 0.0 for my average instead of catching the exception.

Comment: I think you have another logic problem somewhere in you program.  Try running without catching any exceptions.  I would also put you exception handling around the code that the exception is supposed to catch.  For example, put IOError handler around code that opens file, DivisionByZero handler around division, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no ZeroDivisionError in your file. Because in your for loop, you have incremented counter variable by 1 already. Unless, the for loop is iterating into an empty object.

Hence, your average = total / counter will always start as:

average = total / 1 (since counter = counter + 1)

Hope it helped.